# Mozilla doesn't show centerd text

Tags: css, text, mozilla

I'm trying to understand why in Mozilla this text is [not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDTIw.png) but as soon as you resize the window it resets in the [right position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqmTD.png).

```css
.shape {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  right: 20%;
  width: 58%;
  height: 62%;
  background: #E8E8E8;
  color: black;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: -100%;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;
  animation: slide 1s forwards;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-family: "Basic", serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  padding-left: 12%;
  padding-right: 12%;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}
```

Here's the website

marcotronconi.com/about.html

P.S. Sorry for the silly question but i'm not really into coding, thanks

Comment: Can't see the problem you have. It's centered because of text-align: center;

Comment: Your code snippet has css only, it's not run-able without html.

Comment: On your webpage, I can't reproduce the problem. The text is in the right position immediately. Anyway, but as I commented on the previous version of your question, there are a lot of -webkit-only properties in the stylesheet, so naturally it will look different in other browsers.

Comment: I noticed that when the page loads the text zooms down from the top in the center, and then shifts to the left when the animation is complete. Then it shifts back to the center when the page is resized. Also, it's really strange - if you have Developer Tools inspector open and you reload the page, then the text shifts to the correct position simply by hovering your cursor over the Developer Tools window.

Comment: But *then* if you close the Developer Tools window... the text shifts back to the left again!